# Is it permissible to save the CVV of a charging card option

Tags: quality-assurance, security

Can we save CVV if we have a *save your card* option? 
What is a secure way to save cvv?
What are the security threats?

Comment: Voting to close this question as off-topic, I think this would be better placed in https://security.stackexchange.com/